# trying to build a basic query string with jquery for autofill on form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so I am just trying to grab data on a current HTML page and build an array and params of a simple data grab, then set that query string to replace the current buttons URL JS is not my strong area any help greatly appreciated.

Firstly I can't get the email to come back clean its always has encoding issues.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var id6 = $(".shipping-name").text();
  var id7 = $(".email_container a").text();
  var id7e = encodeURIComponent(id7);
  var id7d = decodeURIComponent(id7e);

  var dataa = {
    id6: id6,
    id7: id7d,
    arr: "foo",
  };

  var dataout = $.param(dataa);
  alert(dataout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order_detail_block span4">
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li class="bold shipping_address_title">Billing and Shipping Address <a href="#" id="copy_ship_address"><i class="fas fa-copy muted"></i></a></li>
    <li class="shipping-name">first last</li>
    <li class="shipping-address1">123 main St</li>
    <li class="shipping-city-state-postalcode">Saint Paul, NE 68873</li>

    <li class="shipping-phone">1234567890</li>
  </ul>

  <div><a id="sr" href="#123" class="btn btn-small btn-customer-service\" target="_blank">Test form auto fill</a></div>

  <div>

    <ul class="unstyled" id="order_details_container" data-orderid="39106419">
      <li><b>Order Details</b></li>
      <li class="email_container">
        <a href="mailto:emailtest@gmaill.com?subject=Order%20100118938"><i class="fas fa-envelope muted"></i> emailtest@gmaill.com</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        102XXXXXXXX
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't call `encodeURIComponent()`, `$.param()` does that for you.

Comment: So you're getting double encoding.

Comment: thank you, you were correct

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was that I was in fact double encoding!